# My countdown timer does not work properly

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer that does something after every X seconds.
When the seconds are few, let's say 6 .. it works correctly, but when the seconds are many lets say 240 , it prints out a log like this:

```
2019-02-08 16:40:18.160 23195-23195/com.pondhoppers.riptide.app I/System.out:  waiting time left - 47
2019-02-08 16:40:18.181 23195-23195/com.pondhoppers.riptide.app I/System.out: waiting time left - 41
2019-02-08 16:40:18.208 23195-23195/com.pondhoppers.riptide.app I/System.out: waiting time left - 35
2019-02-08 16:40:18.233 23195-23195/com.pondhoppers.riptide.app I/System.out: waiting time left - 29
2019-02-08 16:40:18.298 23195-23195/com.pondhoppers.riptide.app I/System.out: waiting time left - 23
2019-02-08 16:40:18.323 23195-23195/com.pondhoppers.riptide.app I/System.out: waiting time left - 3
```

code:

```
new CountDownTimer(240000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public final void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {
        System.out.println("waiting time left - " + (int) (millisUntilFinished * .001f));
        tvRaffleCount.setText(String.valueOf((Integer.valueOf(countDown)-1000)* 60000));
    }

    @Override
    public final void onFinish() {
        try {
            tvRaffleCount.setText("");
        } catch (Exception v) {
            //raffle mode is off
            v.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}.start();
```

Comment: I decided to do it in a background thread, worked well :)